# finding specific file in command-line

Tags: command-line, grep, beautifulsoup

So I recently downloaded [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/documentation.html#Quick%20Start) and is you'll see in the beginning of the documentation, I need to find the `README.txt` file to get more info on bs4 beta documentaion.

I looked in and around the directory bs4 is in, but it's not there, so I need to find the file.

I am using grep right now, but I ran grep in the command line 20 minutes ago and I still have nothing. This is what I did:

```
grep --include README.txt -l 'Beautiful Soup'
```

Is there something wrong with my code, or is this just an extremely slow method? If it's wrong what is right? if it's just slow, what would be faster?

**note: I have a mac running OSX Mountain Lion. So my command-line is terminal**

Comment: Why don't you just follow the link to the BS4 documentation? http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should look for README.txt with find:

```
find . -name 'README.txt'
```

the "." means that you're searching recursively in the current directory. Replace it with the folder where you want to search

a note: your shell is "bash", that's the default shell in os x terminal and most unix systems

Comment: Using `iname` would offer case insensitive search.